# In Uniprot how do I know which variants are mutations and which are polymorphic?

Tags: uniprot

In Uniprot how do I know which variants are mutations and which are polymorphic?
I am looking at [P38398 (BRCA1_HUMAN)](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P38398#function) specifically.

Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "mutation"? Are you just talking about how frequent a variant is in a population?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is very late but may still help others:
Have a look at the UniProt index of human polymorphisms and disease mutations at https://www.uniprot.org/docs/humsavar

Please don't hesitate to contact the UniProt helpdesk if you have any additional questions.

Comment: Thanks for answering! No answer is ever late here, the objetive of this site to to amass a collection of useful Q&As, so the age of a question is irrelevant as long as it could still be asked by someone else. If, as your answer seems to suggest, you are affiliated with UniProt, it would be helpful if you could mention that since it would add more weight to your answers.